# AWS Request Expired Error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to execute a script in which an AWS security group is created using NodeJS. When I try and run the script I get an error saying:

```
Error { RequestExpired: Request has expired.
```

Has anyone seen this? What does it mean? I thought the time between my local machine and the AWS Host might be off so I set a new timezone in my script to make up for the difference but still same error.

Comment: What is the functionality of the script? Which aws service is uses? Can you show the script?

Comment: I figured out the error, the issue wasn't a timestamp, my token had just expired. :)